# Is there a scriptable method for testing duplex settings on network interfaces?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, networking, settings, automated-testing

I'm looking to test, on a large number of servers, whether or not the duplex settings on the network interfaces have been set up properly.

Is there a tool, or set of scripts, which I can run against the servers, to test their settings?

The servers in question are Windows 2003 and windows 2008 machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplex setting is very eratic with regards to scripting support.  Some vendors (such as Intel) give a WMI provider that gives it, others write to the registry and text files blah blah blah.  You can get link speed pretty reliably, but duplex settings can be problematic.

Comment: I wonder if this might be more reliable through SNMP.

Comment: I'm looking for any automated test, really, which can reliably tell me whether the connection is set to full-duplex.

Comment: You're going to have a lot better luck getting that from the switch than from Windows thanks to, as squillman says, NIC driver inconsistency.